# Will I be denied student visa?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, removal

I traveled from the Bahamas to the UK a few days ago embark on a 1yr foundation program. I was told by the international student advisor that I should travel to the UK and begin my program and work on my obtaining my visa while in the UK. Upon my arrival I told the immigration officer that I am there to study but I don't have a visa and what was told to me. I was then detained and sent home. They officer told me that it is not deportation or a band just refusal because I didn't have a student visa and I would not be penalized when applying for my student visa seeing that I was misinformed. What do you think? Will this pose as a problem when I submit my visa application.

Comment: It seems like you were already given an answer by an official of the agency most likely to know.

Comment: The "international student advisor" is an idiot and you should bring this up with his or her superior.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I would be wondering if the school is a scam.